# How to add Border around Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, border

I would like to merge a "drawRectF-like thing" with a Bitmap OR simple apply a border to a Bitmap in some way.

I don't want something like this:

```
Canvas.drawRectF(bitmap.x, bitmap.y, bitmap.x1, bitmap.y1)
Canvas.draw(bitmap)
```

I want to be able to apply the border to the Bitmap only once, then when I simply call Canvas.draw(bitmap) the border will be there around the bitmap.

It is preferable that the border has rounded corners.

Answer (score -1):

First create a new canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into:

> Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bitmap);

Then draw the border using this canvas:

> canvas1.drawRectF(x, y, x1, y1);

Finally draw the bitmap to the first canvas.

> canvas.draw(bitmap);

**Note:** For this to work, the bitmap must be mutable.

Comment: He wrote in the second sentence that he *don't* want to use that method.

Comment: This does not work for me. No errors, no border! Don't understand how this could work at all tbh.

Comment: @bos This is not what he mentioned. Here I'm drawing the border directly on a mutable bitmap. The bitmap will now have the border permanently on it. After that it can be drawn any number of times on other canvases. Why then the negative vote?